# Designing an API where an image can be supplied

Tags: c#, api, api-design

I am designing an API whereby some other system can supply an image in their `POST`. As such this is an API for integration purposes, with no front-end. Postman is used for testing the API.

Below is the DTO for the expected `POST` body written in C#

```
   public class VideoEventCreateDto
    {

        public double Confidence { get; set; } = 1;
        [Required]
        public DateTime EventTimeStamp { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Base64Image { get; set; }
        public string ImageFileName { get; set; }   
        [Required]
        public ImageType ImageFileType { get; set; }
    }
```

I have two questions:

Question 1

- According to this article, using Base64 for the image is an old technique that should be avoided: https://tyk.io/api-design-guidance-file-upload/ . However, their alternative solutions seem to relate to having a front-end and only uploading an image by itself. What would be the best solution to change my API to not use Base 64?

Question 2

- The `ImageType` is an enum with a list of the supported file extensions. This is useful as it forces the consumer to select from a list of supported file types when the developer reads the API documentation. This will make the API more robust, as it will significantly reduce the likelihood of the consumer supplying an unsupported file type at runtime. However, this information is essentially duplicated in the `ImageFileName` property by virtue of the fact that it will have a file extension e.g. "myImage.png". Is this an acceptable design?

Answer (score 1):

For your Question 2, the ImageType enum is unnecessary ducplication. Nothing would prevent a consumer from sending the selected enum field with a diferent file type. You can inform in the API documentation, but should enforce verification using the posted file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of posting a single Dto, I think it should be possible to have your metadata as part of the URL, either as part of the route or as query parameters, and have a binary body for the image data.  I.e. if using ASP.Net use a method signature something like

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/imageupload/{filename}")]
public byte[] Upload([FromBody] byte[] imageData, [FromRoute] string filename, [FromQuery] DateTime EventTimeStamp)
```

Note that I'm not very experienced with asp.net, so there might be issues I'm not aware of with this approach. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316269/is-it-possible-to-combine-fromroute-and-frombody-in-asp-net-core) for combining body and query parameters in the same request object.

Regarding your second question, I would be concerned with users lying about the image type. So you would still need to validate the actual image file, and also ensure the actual file format matches the claimed image type. While it might avoid some mistakes, I would also expect all users to actually test their application, and that they would discover incorrect usage then. It would be up you you if you consider it worth the effort.